# Amazon aws s3 static website hosting redirection not working

Tags: amazon-web-services, redirect, amazon-s3, website-hosting

I config the redirection rules like following, but it doesn't work, which return 404 "not found" error.

```
<RoutingRules>
<RoutingRule>
    <Condition>
        <HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>404</HttpErrorCodeReturnedEquals>
    </Condition>
    <Redirect>
        <Protocol>https</Protocol>
        <HostName>wmy59ckuro.execute-api.us-west-2.amazonaws.com</HostName>
        <ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>beta/image/resize?key=</ReplaceKeyPrefixWith>
        <HttpRedirectCode>307</HttpRedirectCode>
    </Redirect>
    </RoutingRule>
</RoutingRules>
```

404 response from s3, Content-type: application/xml.

```
<Error>
<Code>NoSuchKey</Code>
<Message>The specified key does not exist.</Message>
<Key>test/featured1_145_160.jpg</Key>
<RequestId>1C6B9F48E730242D</RequestId>
<HostId>
ul8Z/wJl7/o9qJR/949+tCperGl88vJbEl4p+0P/eXdZ44CoF5t8C/iu61TaHBhLrLwMIzx7h5M=
</HostId>
</Error>
```

The purpose of the redirection is to redirect any 404 hits to an aws api gateway route for image resizing, when finish then redirect back to s3 url, I have api gateway redirecting back to s3 bit working, which is the 2nd redirection. Now is having this first redirect not working.

Can anyone shed a light, I almost give up. I don't have aws technique support.

Comment: If it is "not working," what does it do instead of working?

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot it returns 404 error screen as if there is no redirection rules setup.

Comment: Is the error coming back to you as HTML or XML?

Comment: XML, content-type: application/xml. I included it in the post.

Comment: So you did.  My oversight.  This means you are using the wrong endpoint.  I'm closing this question as a duplicate of another question, where you'll find the solution.

Comment: Thanks heaps. That was the issue. really appreciate your help here.